# Get $a$ and $b$ from $ax^2 + bx + c$ if $x$ and $c$ are known

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I already know the values $x, c$ and $y$ in this equation: $y = ax^2 + bx + c$

I would like to know one or more methods for finding the values of a and b.

Comment: what are the values?

Comment: This is a set of values, not a single pair. Fix $b$ and then you can derive $a$ as a function of $b$

Comment: You are not able to find a unique $(a,b)$ if one point is given however if there are two points given then you can form simultaneous equations and solve a and b.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting the known values you find an eqaution in the two unknown $a,b$ that,if $x\ne 0$,has infintely many solutions of the form:
$$
a=\frac{y-bx-c}{x^2}
$$

if $x=0$ than the equation is an identity if $y=c$ and has no solutions in $y \ne c$.